# Returning and collating instances of arbitrary text in files (plus some other requirements)

Tags: regex, collation, text-processing

I have a job that doesn't seem super difficult, but i'm not clever enough to know where to start. :)

So i have a number of files that contain lines with names on the end, something like this:

```
File 001:
blahblahblahblahblah:Mrs Jane Doe
blahblahblahblahblah:John Doe
blahblahblahblahblah:Joe Bloggs

File 002:
blahblahblahblahblah:Dr Jane Doe
blahblahblahblahblah:John Doe
blahblahblahblahblah:Joe Bloggs
blahblahblahblahblah:Fred Bloggs

...
```

And so on. What i would like to do is have a script go through all of these files and return output like this:

```
John Doe
001
002
...

Fred Bloggs
002
...
```

But i DON'T know what the names are, so it needs to find them (easy enough with regexp obviously) and then *collate* them on its own.

On top of that, it ALSO needs to take into account the case of Jane Doe above, where she appears in different places with different titles. Ideally i would like the output for her to be something like the following:

```
Jane Doe
001 - Mrs
002 - Dr
...
```

So this script would need to be able to exclude certain terms (which i'd provide, of course) for the purposes of collation, but be smart enough to add those terms back into my results so i can keep track of the changes.

Is this something i can do with a single tool like awk, or am i looking at like a Ruby/Python/perl script sort of job? If the latter, could someone point me to the functions or libraries or whatever i might want to use? (I'm kind of mediocre at scripting/programming but with sufficient documentation i can usually muddle through eventually)

Cheers!

**Edit:** Seems i've managed it on my own. :) Here's what i did, in case anyone runs across this in the future:

1. I merged all of my names into a single file and stripped all of the titles, like this:

```
cat * | \
    perl -pe 's/^(Dr |Mrs |Mr |blahblah )//ig' | \
    sort | \
    uniq -i > \
    notitles.txt
```

2. I looped through the resulting file with grep:

```
while read name; do
    export fname="`echo $name | perl -pe 's/[\r\n]//g'`"
    echo "\n=={$fname}=="
    egrep -i "$name" * | \
        sed -E 's/\.txt:/ /g' | \
        perl -pe 's/(?<!==)$ENV{"fname"}//ig'
done < notitles.txt
```

And then i got my list of names like i wanted!

Comment: first you should read files then filter them to find title and name. i mean for "DR, MR, MRS". If you have title list i think you can do this job easily. If you have title list, i can help you about the steps or script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Seems i managed it on my own though, see edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty easy to implement with the help of `awk`.
I create two files named by ID: `001`, `002`. And put them in a directory.

```
$ ls *
001  002

$ gawk -F: '{sub(/^(Dr|Mrs|Mr|Miss) +/, "", $2); a[$2]=a[$2]FILENAME":"}; END{for(i in a)printf("%s:%s\n", i, a[i])}' * | sort | tr : '\n'
Fred Bloggs
002

Jane Doe
001
002

Joe Bloggs
001
002

John Doe
001
002
```

---

```
$ gawk -F: '
{
    if(match($2, /^(Dr|Mrs|Mr) +/, m)) {
        t = " - " substr($2, m[1, "start"], m[1, "length"])
        n = substr($2, m[0, "start"]+m[0, "length"])
    }
    else {
        t = ""
        n = $2
    }
    a[n] = a[n] FILENAME t ":"
}
END{
    for(i in a)
        printf("%s:%s\n", i, a[i])
}' * | sort | tr : '\n'

Fred Bloggs
002

Jane Doe
001 - Mrs
002 - Dr

Joe Bloggs
001
002

John Doe
001
002
```